# Lodash isEqual - How to get keys of objects that differ

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, key, lodash

I'm trying to obtain an array of keys, that were different as a result of comparing two objects. I was only able to do it using `isEqualWith` and `mapKeys`, like so:

```js
const differencies = [];
const objA = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const objB = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 100
};

function customizer(objOne, objTwo) {
  if (lodash.isEqual(objOne, objTwo)) {
    return true;
  }

  lodash.mapKeys(objOne, (value, key) => {
    if (value !== objTwo[key]) {
      differencies.push(key);
    }
  });

  return false;
}

lodash.isEqualWith(objA, objB, customizer);
console.log(differencies);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>const lodash = _;</script>
```

**Question is**: *Is there a better way to get keys of objects that differ using lodash?*

Comment: Do you only want to compare flat objects? Or would there be nesting, e.g., `{a: 1, b: { c: 2}}`? If so, how should the differences be reported in that case?

Comment: @VLAZ flat only and the keys of objects are always the same (only values may vary)

Comment: OK, next question - is one object supposed to be the source of truth? Right now if you compare `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{a: 1, c: 3}` the result says `["b"]` - is this correct? Or should it say `["b", "c"]`? EDIT: OK, saw your edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to compare objects where the keys are identical but values might differ, you can leverage [`keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#keys) or [`keysIn()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#keysIn) (if you want to also traverse the prototype chain) and remove all entries that do not have a matching value with [`filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter).

```js
const objA = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 };
const objB = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 100 };

const differencies = lodash.filter(
  lodash.keys(objA), 
  key => objA[key] !== objB[key]
);
console.log(differencies);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>const lodash = _;</script>
```

Alternatively using [chaining syntax](https://lodash.com/docs/#lodash):

```js
const objA = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 };
const objB = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 100 };

const differencies = lodash(objA)
  .keys()
  .filter(key => objA[key] !== objB[key]);
console.log(differencies);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>const lodash = _;</script>
```

For this sort of functionality, Lodash might be an overkill. Simple JavaScript equivalent is [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const objA = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 };
const objB = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 100 };

const differencies = Object.keys(objA)
  .filter(key => objA[key] !== objB[key]);
console.log(differencies);
```